# Does iOS 13 or Safari create automatic reminders based on visiting a website?

Tags: iphone, ios, safari, reminders

We run a web app that deals with "events" (generalized description, but good enough for this purpose). Each event has a page, with a due date. The event organizer creates the event page, including setting the due date, through our web app. Over the course of the usage of this app, they would also visit another page for the event that includes a simple javascript count-down timer to the due date. Our web app does not do any browser-based or "push" notifications that we are aware of.

We have been getting reports from a small number of our users that ask us to stop sending them reminders about their event after the due date has passed. The problem is that we do not, as far as we know, send any such reminders. These users have exclusively been on iPhone and iOS 13. With users that provide more information, it seems that the reminder is coming from Safari and they are able to delete/remove it.

What we're wondering is:

- In iOS 13, are any such reminders set automatically, without the user needing to set them themselves? Or are all reminders created with explicit user action/consent?
- Any tips for us being able to reproduce this issue on our test iPhones? We have been unable to do so thus far.

Comment: You should remove the developer question at the end to avoid your quesiton being considered off-topic for this site.  Your other two points are on-topic here so those look ok.

Comment: @fsb thank you, I have done so. I assume that question is more appropriate for StackOverflow, once we have a better understanding of the mechanism through which this is happening.